# ReactJS key для child-элементов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Стоит задача вывести элементы из JSON, которые будут изменяться пользователем. Проблема появляется при выводе массива:

```
let items = this.props.doc.map(function(item, index) {
      <item key={index} data={item} onChange={this.onChange} />
}

return {items}
```

Приведу пример JSON (выводим элементы из `group`):

```
{
"just": "example",
"too": "example",
"group": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "type": "Model"
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "type": "Model"
    }
  ]
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при удалении элемента из `state` родителя в котором хранится JSON, `key` у child'ов меняется т.к. это индекс массива, а React пытается рендерить думая, что ключи не изменились (визуально удаляет не тот элемент, хотя в `state` все правильно).

У элементов изначально нет ничего уникального, что можно было бы использовать за `key`.

Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Если использовать совершенно рандомный ключ (например `Math.random()`, хоть и так нельзя ), то React перерендеривает целиком каждый раз, но удаление работает корректно.

P.S. JSON каждый раз разный и что-то добавлять от себя в него нельзя

Comment: А других вариантов нет. Единственное, если исходные данные менять не хочется, то можно их в другую структуру распарсить [{ key=json }] и уже с ней работать.

Comment: ИМХО: Стоит по возможности привести исходные данные к структуре
`"group": { "id": {"name": "", } }`.
Другим вариантом решения будет передача каждого элемента группы в отдельный компонент и проверки данных через shouldComponentUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что у вас key - это номер элемента в массиве. Делать так - не самая лучшая практика. Используйте уникальные данные для key. В вашем случае, это может выглядеть так:

```
let items = this.props.doc.map(function(item, index) {
      <item key={item.name + item.type} data={item} onChange={this.onChange} />
}
```

П.С. это при условии, что name и type - уникальное сочетание для вашего айтема, что скорее всего так и есть.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно в сам JSON добавить каждому объекту ключ:значение, по типу "id": "1" и использовать для ключа